# Map vertex id to vertex coordinate

Tags: map, coordinate

I want to map vertex labels to vertex coordinates stored in two variables.

```
vl = {6, 9, 12}
vd = {{1011, 1127, 420}, {950, 1052, 404}, {780, 1033, 470}}
```

I tried,

```
coords = {vl -> vd}
```

but this didn't work. May I know what's the right way to do this?

Expected output:

```
{6 -> {1011, 1127, 420}, 9 -> {950, 1052, 404}, 12 -> {780, 1033, 470}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Thread[vl -> vd]
```

> ```
> {6 -> {1011, 1127, 420}, 9 -> {950, 1052, 404}, 12 -> {780, 1033, 470}}
> ```

Also

```
MapThread[Rule] @ {vl, vd}
```

> ```
> {6 -> {1011, 1127, 420}, 9 -> {950, 1052, 404}, 12 -> {780, 1033, 470}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
MapThread[#2 -> #1 &, {vd, vl}]
(*{6 -> {1011, 1127, 420}, 9 -> {950, 1052, 404},12 -> {780, 1033, 470}}*)
```